# Running 7Z in a dos command from VBA Excel causes warning alert

Tags: vba, warnings, alert, 7zip

I am currently using the following code to run a `dos` command as follows from `VBA`.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

dos_command="\\\10.xx.xx.xx\test\7z.exe  a -r " etc etc etc

result = objShell.Run(dos_command, 0, True)

Set objShell =nothing
```

All runs well, the only problem is that I get an annoying Warning Windows Box advising a program is trying to run in my computer, press OK or Cancel

I must use `"objshell"` because I need `VBA` to wait until `DOS` command is completed.

is there a way to avoid the warning box from coming up from within VBA or adding some additional parameters to the DOS command ?

The 7z.exe file is running in a server (not local PC) so I assume that's the problem.

I cannot use or install 7z.exe in each machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three options, presented in order from quickest/dirtiest to most robust:

1. **Create a text file as part of command line and wait for its existence**: modify your command line to something like this and run it using `Shell` (not your `objShell`):

   ```
   dos_command = "\\\10.xx.xx.xx\test\7z.exe  a -r " etc etc etc
   dos_command = dos_command & " && echo > " & TempFileName
   ```

   This will create a text file named `TempFileName` **after** your 7-zip code completes.  You just need to make sure `TempFileName` does not exist before you run your shell command, then run the command and wait for the `TempFileName` file to exist.
2. **Use `OpenProcess` and `GetExitCodeProcess` APIs**: launch your command line using the [OpenProcess](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/OpenProcess.shtml) API call which provides access to your new process (note that the `Shell` function returns the ProcessID of the launched process).  Then use the ProcessID to sit in a loop and poll the process via [GetExitCodeProcess](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/GetExitCodeProcess.shtml).  Relevant declarations:

   ```
   Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
           (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
            ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
            ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
   Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
           (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
            lpExitCode As Long) As Long
   Private Const STILL_ACTIVE = &H103
   Private Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400

   '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------vv
   ' Procedure : ShellWait
   ' DateTime  : 2/15/2008 10:59
   ' Author    : Mike
   ' Purpose   : Executes a shell command and waits for it to complete.
   ' Notes     : Runs the shell as a batch file, allowing the user to pass a string with
   '             line breaks to execute a multi-line command.
   '
   '           : Provides two means to break out of the loop.
   '             1) Provide a timeout in seconds.
   '                The code breaks out once it reaches the timeout.
   '             2) Provide a flag to tell the procedure to stop running.
   '                To use this option, you would need to pass the procedure a global flag
   '                that the user has the ability to change through the interface.
   ' Update (5/23/2008):
   '           - Uses a progressive sleep timer to allow fast processes to run quickly
   '               and long processes to get increasing clock cycles to work with.
   '           - Changed default window mode to hidden.
   '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   '^^
   Public Function ShellWait(DosCmd As String, _
                             Optional StartIn As String = "WINDOWS TEMP FOLDER", _
                             Optional WindowStyle As VbAppWinStyle = vbHide, _
                             Optional TimeOutSeconds As Long = -1, _
                             Optional ByRef StopWaiting As Boolean = False)    'vv
       On Error GoTo Err_ShellWait

       Dim hProcess As Long, RetVal As Long, StartTime As Long
       Dim BatName As String, FileNum As Integer, SleepTime As Long

       StartTime = Timer

       BatName = TempFileName(StartIn, "bat")
       FileNum = FreeFile()
       Open BatName For Output As #FileNum
       ChDrive Left(BatName, 1)
       ChDir Left(BatName, InStrRev(BatName, "\"))
       Print #FileNum, DosCmd
       Close #FileNum

       hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, Shell(BatName, WindowStyle))
       SleepTime = 10
       Do
           'Get the status of the process
           GetExitCodeProcess hProcess, RetVal
           DoEvents: Sleep SleepTime
           If TimeOutSeconds <> -1 Then
               If Timer - StartTime > TimeOutSeconds Then Exit Do
           End If
           If StopWaiting Then Exit Do
           'Progressively increase the SleepTime by 10%
           '  This allows a quick process to finish quickly, while providing
           '  a long process with increasingly greater clock cycles to work with
           SleepTime = SleepTime * 1.1
       Loop While RetVal = STILL_ACTIVE
       Kill BatName

   Exit_ShellWait:
       Exit Function
   Err_ShellWait:
       MsgBox Err.Description
       Resume Exit_ShellWait
   End Function

   '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------vv
   ' Procedure : TempFileName
   ' DateTime  : 12/9/08
   ' Author    : Mike
   ' Purpose   : Returns an unused file name but does not create the file.  Path can be
   '             passed with or without the trailing '\'.
   ' Requires  : TempPath() function
   '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   '^^
   Function TempFileName(Optional ByVal Path As String = "WINDOWS TEMP FOLDER", _
                         Optional Ext As String = "txt", _
                         Optional Prefix As String = "temp") As String    'vv
   Dim TempFName As String, i As Integer

       If Path = "WINDOWS TEMP FOLDER" Then Path = TempPath
       If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
       If Not (Path Like "?:\*" Or Path Like "\\*") Then
           Err.Raise 52    '"Bad file name or number."
       ElseIf Dir(Path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
           Err.Raise 76    '"Path not found."
       End If

       TempFName = Path & Prefix & "." & Ext
       For i = 1 To 500
           If Dir(TempFName) = "" Then
               TempFileName = TempFName
               GoTo Exit_TempFileName
           End If
           TempFName = Path & Prefix & "_" & Format(i, "000") & "." & Ext
       Next i
       TempFileName = ""

   End Function

   '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ' Procedure : TempPath
   ' Author    : Mike
   ' Date      : 8/12/2008
   ' Purpose   : Returns something like:
   '               C:\DOCUME~1\BGRAND~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\
   '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   '^^
   Function TempPath() As String    'vv
   Const TemporaryFolder = 2
   Static TempFolderPath As String
   Dim fs As Object
       If Len(TempFolderPath) = 0 Then
           Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
           TempFolderPath = fs.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder) & "\"
       End If
       TempPath = TempFolderPath
   End Function
   ```
3. **Use CreateProcess and WaitForSingleObject APIs**: refer to the "Super Shell" example at this help page for [CreateProcess](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/CreateProcess.shtml)

Comment: Thanks mwolfe02

Option 1 is the one I had originally, but I would like to stop using it for a number of reasons.

Option 2 seems like what I am after, however I am not able to make work. The examples shown on your links to AllAPI.net as well as the test is, well, rather confusing to me.

I have tried a number of things, without success.
Note that, although I am an advanced VBA programmer, I cannot say the same about API's...:(

' ?????
lngHwndProcess = OpenProcess(dos_command, 0, 0)  'lngProcessIDs(lngLoop))
                     
Do While xxxx <> lngHwndProcess
    ' GetExitCodeProcess
Loop

Comment: @user1135218: I added a bunch of sample code to Option 2.  I have not updated it in years and there are some things I might do differently now, but it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks mwolfe02. I gave a go at your code but I guess I am not as good in Excel/VBA as i thought I was.
I just couldn't make sense of it..:(
Anyway, I have gone back to option 1 you mentioned, which is what I was using and unfortunately will continue to use...

Answer (score 1):

**Calling `Microsoft® Windows® Script Host` causes windows to display the message. Instead try this**

```
Public Sub test()
   Dim dos_command$, lRet&
   dos_command = """\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\xxx\xxx\7z.exe"" a test.zip ""\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\xxx\xxx\*.log"" -r"
   lRet = Shell(dos_command, vbMaximizedFocus)
   MsgBox lRet
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

*You may do the following and use your code:*

- Open Start | Run and type `gpedit.msc`. Click OK
- User Configuration >> Administrative Templates >> Windows Components >> Attachment Manager
- Add 7z.exe to the Inclusion list for moderate risk file types setting.

---

Hpe this helps

Comment: Thanks for response. I was using before the code you mentioned, however I need the dos command to finish executing BEFORE proceeding with the next VBA code. "objShell." does that.
Putting a WAIT 5 seconds (for example) routine simply is not good, as sometimes the dos command needs 2 seconds to finish, sometimes 10 seconds, etc

Comment: Thanks for your update and ideas. Unfortunately running gpedit.msc on >100 Pc's is not possible.